# How to tell if someone came to my website from facebook using mobile app

Tags: php, android, facebook

I have the following php code on my server that allows me to tell if user cam to my webpage from facebook:

```
if ($_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER] == "https://www.facebook.com/") {  do stuff }
```

So, the problem here is that people are also using facebook on mobile using facebook app, so I don't get the referral link this way.

Is there any way I can tell if someone came to my webpage clicking on a link using facebook app?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a regex for matching.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

For example

```
if (preg_match("/.*\.(facebook|fbdcn)\.com/i", $_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER])) {
    echo "A match was found.";
} else {
    echo "A match was not found.";
}
```

You can use this site to find a good regex.

https://regex101.com/

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. It is probably safer to use regex, but my main problem is how to check if someone came from facebook if he is using the facebook app

Comment: I suggest you to create a 'debug php script' which dumps all date from the request to a log or the browser. After that just surf with the app to this page to see what you get. I use for this phpinfo() which I remove after the tests.

Comment: It worked using your regexp. I didn't know that facebook apps make referer links. Thank you